# I understand what not in does in sql but I'm confused what it does when there are two things

Tags: mysql, sql

Does it compare buy_ccy to sell_ccy in the second select? Then the sell_ccy to the buy_ccy? Does the order of the second select statement matter? Thank you in advance! :)

```
select 
    customer,order_no,buy_ccy,sell_ccy 
from 
    fxbook f1
where 
    (buy_ccy,sell_ccy) not in (select 
                                    sell_ccy,buy_ccy 
                               from 
                                    fxbook
                               where 
                                    f1.customer <> customer)"
```

Comment: Yes it does compare as you would think, and yes, the order does matter.  Switch around the `select` from the subquery.

Comment: NOT IN is a bit tricky when null values are returned from the sub-query. Consider NOT EXISTS instead.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-column IN() comparison simply compares ALL columns in the order you present them, but here is a good reason why you should include table aliases in column references:

```
where          (f1.buy_ccy    , f1.sell_ccy) 
not in (select fxbook.sell_ccy, fxbook.buy_ccy from fxbook ...)

SO  f1.buy_ccy  compares to fxbook.sell_ccy 
AND f1.sell_ccy compares to fxbook.buy_ccy
```

Think of `NOT` as just `the inverse of`. Here, if there is a match this gets converted to false, and if there was no match that gets converted to true. The rows that are true are the ones that get returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would caution you from using `not in` with a subquery.  If any value in the subquery is `null`, then no rows are returned at all.

For this reason, I strongly recommend `not exists` with subqueries:

```
select f.*
from fxbook f
where not exists (select 1
                  from fxbook f2
                  where f2.buy_ccy = f.buy_ccy and
                        f2.sell_ccy = f.sell_ccy and
                        f2.customer <> f.customer
                 );
```